# Как вставить проверку в код цикла

Tags: php, printf

У меня есть частичка кода, которая выводит информацию с бд.

```
<?php 

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT blogdata.id, blogdata.name, blogdata.date, blogdata.tags, blogdata.text, blogdata.comment, categories.title, (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM comments WHERE comments.post=blogdata.id) AS count FROM blogdata INNER JOIN categories ON (blogdata.tags=categories.id) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $num", $db);

if (!$result)
{
echo "<p>Ошибка!</p>";
exit (mysql_error());
}
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
do
{       
printf ("
<table style='width:600px' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='BlogStripe'>
<tr>
<td rowspan='4' class='BlogStripeLeft' style='width:4px'></td>
<td rowspan='4' style='width:10px'></td>
<td style='width:480px; height:4px'></td>
<td style='width: 113px; height:4px'></td>
<td style='width:4px; height:4px'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='width:480px'><div class='BlogTopic'>
<a href='item/view_post.php?id=%s'>%s</a></div></td>  
<td class='BlogSmall' rowspan='2'  style='width:113px'>%s<br>  
<a href='item/view_post.php?id=%s'>Ссылка</a></td>
<td style='width:4px' rowspan='2'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>рубрика: <a href='tags/view_cat.php?tags=%s'> %s  </a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='height:4px'></td>
<td style='width:113px; height:4px'></td>
<td style='width:4px; height:4px'></td>
</tr>
</table> 
<table style='width:600px' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr><td>%s</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style='text-align:right; vertical-align: top;'> <a href='item/view_post.php?id=%s'>комментарии (%s) </a></td></tr></table>  <div style='height:20px'></div>", $myrow ["id"], $myrow ["name"], $myrow ["date"], $myrow ["id"], $myrow ["tags"], $myrow ["title"], $myrow ["text"], $myrow ["id"], $myrow ["count"]);
}

while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array ($result));
?>
```

Но я хочу, например, задать условие

```
    <?php
if ($comment==1) { print "<a href=item/view_post.php?id=%s>комментарии (%s) </a>"; } 
else { print "<p>Нет комментариев</p>"; }
?>
```

Как мне это реализовать в моем случае? В printf вставить не получается. 
Или это можно как-то по-другому сделать? 
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для красоты сложите это все в одну переменную заранее:

```
    $buf = "
    <table style='width:600px' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='BlogStripe'>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan='4' class='BlogStripeLeft' style='width:4px'></td>
    <td rowspan='4' style='width:10px'></td>
    <td style='width:480px; height:4px'></td>
    <td style='width: 113px; height:4px'></td>
    <td style='width:4px; height:4px'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style='width:480px'><div class='BlogTopic'>
    <a href='item/view_post.php?id=%s'>%s</a></div></td>  
    <td class='BlogSmall' rowspan='2'  style='width:113px'>%s<br>  
    <a href='item/view_post.php?id=%s'>Ссылка</a></td>
    <td style='width:4px' rowspan='2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>рубрика: <a href='tags/view_cat.php?tags=%s'> %s  </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style='height:4px'></td>
    <td style='width:113px; height:4px'></td>
    <td style='width:4px; height:4px'></td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
    <table style='width:600px' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr><td>%s</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style='text-align:right; vertical-align: top;'>";

// вот ваша логика    
if ($myrow['comment'] == 1) {
    $buf .= "<a href='item/view_post.php?id=%s'>комментарии (%s) </a>";
    $buf .= "</td></tr></table>  <div style='height:20px'></div>";
    printf ($buf, $myrow ["id"], $myrow ["name"], $myrow ["date"], $myrow ["id"], $myrow ["tags"], $myrow ["title"], $myrow ["text"], $myrow ["id"], $myrow ["count"], /*переменная в которой id коментария, дважды что бы заполнить два %s*/);
}
else {
    $buf .= "<p>Нет комментариев</p>";
    $buf .= "</td></tr></table>  <div style='height:20px'></div>";
    printf ($buf, $myrow ["id"], $myrow ["name"], $myrow ["date"], $myrow ["id"], $myrow ["tags"], $myrow ["title"], $myrow ["text"], $myrow ["id"], $myrow ["count"]);
}
```

Обратите внимание printf имеют разные списки переменных, в первом необходимо вместо коментария продублировать дважды переменную в которой id коментария, а во втором случаии не нужно, так как вы их не выводите.

Comment: Все работает, только структура почему нарушилась...

Comment: После if строчку забыл:
$buf .= "</td></tr></table>  <div style='height:20px'></div>",
а в самом if этого не должно быть, поправил.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Как Вас еще можно отблагодарить, кроме галочки?) Я впервые здесь задал вопрос, может еще будет нужно обратиться за советом.)

Comment: Кроме галочки можете тыкнуть рядом вверх, но наверное вам пока это не доступно.
Можете просто перейти ко мне в профиль и добавить в закладки, но это как то через чур) Зачем я вам там.
Будет нужно, найдете в профиле свой первый вопрос и найдете меня)

Comment: Стоп. Поспешил. Переменная $comment вроде не передается.. А почему?

Comment: Проверьте то как у вас написан printf, наверное там не указана переменная с коментарием, и вместо $comment вы хотели написать !empty($row['coment']), но тогда сам printf также нужно перенести в if и else с разным списком параметров.

Comment: Я скопировал Ваш код .. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Я уже запутался ..

Comment: Что такое $comment ? Его необходимо инициализировать.

Comment: Переменная. В бд имеет значение 1 или 0. Поэтому я хочу написать, если переменная $comment = 1, тогда выводить ссылку на комментарии, если 0, тогда  нет. Или я неправильно это понимаю?

Comment: В массиве $row у вас что лежит?
Ваши данные я так понимаю все там.
Доступ к ним $row['name'], где name - имя поля в таблице.
Замините $comment на соответствующий элемент из $row и скажите в каком лежит ссылка на коментарий, тогда я смогу вам помочь.

Comment: Блин. Надо было же так написать: if ($myrow ['comment']==1) ..

Comment: Поправил...
Надеюсь у вас все получится.

Comment: Спасибо.) Буду писать Вам еще, если Вы не против.)

Comment: помогите пожалуйста <http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442675/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B>